# Edit button to modify text in textbox in window forms

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, edit

I am trying to create an edit button that will allow me to edit and change existing text in text boxes. I am doing this on window forms in c#. I dont know what code I need to but inside that edit button in order for it to allow me to edit the text when it is running.

Comment: Could you provide your code, please? What *exaclty* do you want to achieve? When user click on the button, what should the edit do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ReadOnly Property.

You set ReadOnly = false on the properties for yourTextBox and when you click the button just execute the code:

```
yourTextBox.ReadOnly = false;
```